# Unity - Quaternion.Slerp in a semisphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a orbit camera who's moving on a semishpere. I have a plane with some other objects over it. In the middle of the scene there is an empty object that i'm using as a pivot for my camera,all is working as intended. I say sempisphere because i do not want to go "under" the plane, infact i have a control to avoid it.

Now i want to look at an object and smmothly rotate in that direction. To do so i'm using this code:

```
void Update () {

         // Smoothly rotates towards target 
         Vector3 targetPoint = myobj.transform.position;
         Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position, Vector3.right);
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

     }
```

[img link 1](https://ibb.co/euNLry)
[img link 2](https://ibb.co/eh2aPJ)

Comment: what is your question? which object do you want to rotate? can you mark the objects on the image so we know which is which? why is your `targetPoint` set to camera position / do you want to rotate an object towards the camera?

Comment: Camera was a typo, i meant a gameobject of the scene. The unique object that is giving me the "error" , in this scene, is the floating green cube. And the resoult of the problem is the second image

Comment: what exactly is "the problem is the second image"? it is very hard to help if you don't mark all the objects so that it is obvious which object in the image is which object in the code. also try to specify what exactly is the current result and what is the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

unless you really want to specify the upward direction as "Vector3.right", just remove the second parameter:

```
void Update()
{
    // Smoothly rotates towards target 
    Vector3 targetPoint = myobj.transform.position;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 2f);
}
```